# android: How To Get SMS Database In The Same Way Used For Contacts?

Tags: android, database, sms

This is my first time working with SMS in android.
First of all have a look at this code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
```

myCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, ContactName + " ASC");

I want to use the same way to get the SMS database and use it.
All I can found on the internet is something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Source: [SmsMmsManager](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging)

But I want something like ContactsContract, but what is it called for SMS?
Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't exist, that I know of.

the sms provider isn't publicly documented. Use it at your own risk. Anything that's not publicly documented but is in AOSP will work, but you're on your own. Not having a contract class is a sign that content://sms isn't meant to be used by the outside world.